# Storing account address

Tags: remix

There are multiple default accounts that are provided by the online Solidity IDE (remix). If I want to store those addresses in a variable, which data type can I use?

Comment: address. like address x = '0xaaabd38c8f1a188a0b8bbf93bdca420cfdd760aa'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a stupid way that use dirrent account call function and then store, a simple contract as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract test{

    address[] addresses;

    function saveAddress(){
        address addr = msg.sender;
        bool flag = contains(addr);
        if (!flag) {
            addresses.push(addr);
        }
    }

    function contains(address _addr) private returns (bool) {
        uint len = addresses.length;
        if (len == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (uint i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
            if (addresses[i] == _addr) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function getAddresses() constant returns (address[]){
        return addresses;
    }

}
```

and then, using different account to call `saveAddress` method. Hope it helps~